# Can I send a spark dataframe as an argument to pandas UDF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible to send a spark dataframe as an argument to a pandas UDF and get a pandas dataframe as return. Below is an example code set I am working with and I am getting error during calling the function:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf



spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("PrimeBatch") \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .getOrCreate()

srcFile = <Some CSV file>
df = spark.read.option("header",True)\
    .csv(srcFile)

# Declare the function and create the UDF
@pandas_udf("Count int")
def count_udf(v: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return v.count()

p_df = count_udf(df)
p_df
```

**The error I am getting when running the code is as below:**

TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: DataFrame[] of type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

**Thanks in advance!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a `Pandas UDF` would take `Pandas.Series`. The `count_udf` function you have defined is just a normal function which takes a *pandas DataFrame* and returns a *pandas DataFrame*.

if you want to convert *spark DataFrame* into a *pandas DataFrame* then you can try the follows:

```
pandas_df  = df.toPandas()
```

you can refer the following link to better understand how to apply a panda UDF:

1. [Introducing vectorized udfs for pyspark](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html)
2. [Spark Pandas UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python-pandas)

Comment: That makes sense..but the toPandas fails when I try it against a big data set..say a 10+ gb file..i think spark tries to load the whole dataset into memory...

Comment: Pandas DataFrame needs to fit in driver memory hence using this method over large datasets is not recommended.